# Integrate camunda dmn modeler in spring mvc application with angular js front end

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, spring, camunda

I have a project in `spring`(backEnd), `angularjs`(frontEnd)

I want to use [dmn modeler](https://github.com/bpmn-io/bower-dmn-js) in my project to create `decision table` and that created decision table(is a xml file) I want to save on server.

I have downloaded `dmn-js` files using `bower`.

I am NOT aware of nodeJS. **I could not get if it requires `nodeJs` then how I can use that in my `spring` project.**

I want to call functions from my `angularJS controller`.

1. `openTable` which accepts `xml` `input`
2. function which give me `xml` (in `string`) as `output`

And also if error is caught in `modelerJS` then to show that in my html.

Any theoretical explanation/useful link would be great !

Comment: To me spring is a time of the year (I know, java is an island) so I can't help with the backend part, but I can tell that you do not need nodejs in order to include dmn-js in your projects. Nodejs is only needed if you want to build the modeler by yourself.

Comment: If I include dmn-modeler.js downloaded by bower in index.html and tried to create dmn table in angular controller with `new Modeler(options)` then it says Modeler is not defined :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I tried so far,

First thing is, I agree with what  #zeropaper written in comment that there is no need of nodeJS

If you look the example given [Here](https://libraries.io/bower/dmn-js)

You need to include `modelerJs` instead `viewerJs` to create table.(of-course other dependencies like `dmn-js` css)

In `angularJS` `controller` you can write something like

```
        var viewer, DmnModeler, initialTemplate;
        DmnModeler = window.DmnJS;

        initialTemplate = ;//xml input (.dmn file)

        viewer = new DmnModeler({ container: '#canvas' });

        viewer.importXML(initialTemplate, function(err) {

          if (!err) {
            console.log('success!');
          } else {
            console.log('something went wrong:', err);
          }
        });
```

For firstTime you can call it with
`viewer.createTemplate(callbackfunction)`

Next time to load it with existing `dmn` you can use `importXML` as shown above.

Next point to get dmn table in xml you can do following,

```
viewer.saveXML({ format: true }, function(err, xml) {
    console.log(xml); //here is xml
});
```

You need an html element say, `<div id='canvas' />` to render view.

Please do comment/correct if I am wrong.